# PHP concatenation outputs extra space

Tags: php, if-statement, concatenation, string-concatenation, conditional-operator

I don't know if I'm doing this right, probably not.

Basically I'm trying to concatenate with some IF conditions. I just got knowledge of thernary operation. Checking the code in firebug, I see some extra space is added between two classes  which causes some problem.

[image]

So far here is the code:

```
<?php 
    $output .= '<span class="ca-icon '.
    (($category->getId()==3)||($category->getId()==4)||($category->getId()==5)||($category->getId()==6)||($category->getId()==7) ? " activeMenuLink " : "").'
    icon-'. strtolower(str_replace($characters,$replacements,Mage::helper('pronav')->__($data['name']))).'"></span>';
?>
```

Comment: after activeMenuLink you have a space then between `'` and icon- you have a space that makes 2 spaces, how many do you see?

Comment: The likely issue is that at the end of line 3 you have .' and then a newline before the continuation of the string.

Comment: @CodeBird: there seem to be 4 spaces ,exactly like I have 4 conditions

Comment: these are the breaks inside your cacatination, put your `'` after the line break. at the place of `'` (enter) icon- put (enter)`'`icon-

Comment: What issues is it causing?

Comment: _“extra space is added between two classes which causes some problem”_ – what would that be? Extra whitespace between class names is no problem at all from an HTML/CSS point of view.

Comment: @CBroe: the problem is that it messes up the rendering of the icon font , which uses the class 'icon-something'. It looks like he icon font doesn't show if there is extra space/weird empty output. It's not really space like a space bar space, it seem to be some empty word. Anyway problem solved, thanks everybody.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php 
    $output .= '<span class="ca-icon '.
    (($category->getId()==3)||($category->getId()==4)||($category->getId()==5)||   ($category->getId()==6)||($category->getId()==7) ? " activeMenuLink " : "")
.'icon-'. strtolower(str_replace($characters,$replacements,Mage::helper('pronav')->__($data['name']))).'"></span>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, that indeed worked out. I Will look closer see what I was missing...

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, there were a litteral new line at the end of line 3, and a few litteral spaces at the beginning of line 4.

Notice the openning "quote" at the end of line 3. This is where your litteral string started.